# AJAX PHP+MySQL - Selectbox

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, drop-down-menu

So I have this simple AJAX example what I want to modify, so when I change the year in the selectbox, I want it to take effect on multiple divs, not only the one with the ID. Any sollution? I was thinking of getelementsbyclassname, but it doesnt show anything.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","proba.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>    
    <select name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
      <option value="">Choose year:</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>    
    </select>
</form>
<br>

<div id="txtHint"><b> - </b></div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` Will work just fine, you just have to iterate the returned items:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    setContent("");
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {

      setContent(xmlhttp.responseText);

    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","proba.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function setContent(content){
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('txtHint');  //fixed syntax error here
    var i = divs.length;

    while(i--) {
          divs[i].innerHTML = content;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>    
    <select name="users" onChange="showUser(this.value)">
      <option value="">Choose year:</option>
      <option value="2013">2013</option>
      <option value="2014">2014</option>    
    </select>
</form>
<br>

<div class="txtHint"><b> - </b></div>
<div class="txtHint"><b> - </b></div>
<div class="txtHint"><b> - </b></div>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by nothing? Try adding console.log(xmlhttp); at the top of your onreadystatechange funtion and update your answer with the results

Comment: I mean, copy+pasted your solution, and it wont show anything.

Comment: @VaimanHunor OK there was a tiny syntax error, i used a comma instead of a semicolon. This is now fixed